# How to stop fetching data sftp?

Tags: sftp

How to **stop fetching data in sftp**? I use *get* for fetching data, but the ETA is too long and therefore I want to stop it. After some search I cannot find the solution. Maybe I use the wrong keywords for the search. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Have you tried Ctrl-C? Most programs should react.

Comment: Thanks @AlexP, the process was interrupted through disconnection. Let me try it next time.